# gtk3 transparent menu's

Tags: menu, gtk, gtk3

Is it possible in gtk3 to create a menu that is transparent? The underling window would use an image as it's background.
I can use a color for the window background but not a image.

Answer (score 0):

I attempted to do what you said using an example from the [gdk2 reference](http://developer.gnome.org/gdk/stable/gdk-Windows.html) by adding a background image first and then porting it to gtk3. I'm no expert at gtk at all, but I did make it somehow compile:

http://pastebin.com/0XwUW5k3 (note that there has to be a "background.png" in the same folder)

The transparent dark rectangle holding the widgets is most likely the box; I tried settings its background color to full transparency as well, but it didn't work, and you'd probably have to do the composing/drawing of it yourself if you wanted it to be completely transparent, but that's not something I'd suggest because it seems too complex..

Also, you might want to create a background image with an already fitting resolution for the window, then you could skip the scaling part.
The scale function originally comes from [this mailling-list thread](http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/cairo/2006-January/006178.html)

Comment: I should have been more clear, I'm trying to use the CSS capabilities in gtk3 to do this.